# How to exclude excess unusable dependencies while optimizing with requireJS?

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs

My js-files probably have some dependencies that really are not necessary inside particular module. js-files are pretty large and they had many edits and deletions before. That's why some js-files could have some dependencies that no longer usable, because related code was deleted from file. However, some dependencies still could present inside `define` call. So, that dependencies are excess dependencies.

How to clean up unusable dependencies? As I understand, requireJS optimizer doesn't remove excess dependencies while optimizing by default. Is it possible to configure requireJS optimizer to make it remove unusable dependencies?

Comment: I suggest software such as [Bower](http://bower.io/) to keep track of your dependencies so that this is not necessary.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are talking about here. RequireJS' optimizer follows the dependencies that **you** specify in your `define` (or `require`) calls. Why you you put "unusable dependencies" there that you'd have to remove later? Maybe you're just not expressing yourself clearly or there's a scenario I'm not considering. In either case, you need to edit your question to clarify what you mean to ask. A [mcve] would do wonders.

Comment: @Louis, I edited my question. Some code fragments were deleted from files, but some related dependencies could still be inside `define` calls. It is pretty hard to check every dependence and remove it manually, because js-files are pretty large.

Comment: Are you using a linter like http://jshint.com or http://eslint.org to catch unused parameters in the define block?  It will help in the case where, e.g. jquery isn't used in a block and you have define(['jquery'], function ($) {...}), as JSHint will flag '$' as defined but never used.  But it won't help in the case where you have define(['jquery], function () {...}), since 'jquery' is just in the module dependencies and there is no parameter for JSHint to check.